# Overwrite the == operator globally

Tags: c#, string, silverlight

In a lot of places I'm using the == operator to compare the string, now I know this considers casing... Is there anyway I can adjust the culture settings to avoid this or do I have to go to every line of code and change it to

```
string.Compare(a,b,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: You could make an extension method.

Comment: While I think you can override the functionallity it may make it harder for the next person to read the code and really see whats going on.  I recommend making an extension method to compare the string, and yes update all the code accordingly.

Comment: You will be unable to override the behavior of String. Besides you should have known better then to use == since that doesn't compare the two strings to see if they are equal.  Using an extension method really isn't suitable for a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound: "Besides you should have known better then to use == since that doesn't compare the two strings to see if they are equal". This isn't true. Strings are comparable using `==`, since they override it. Most reference types don't, but it's easily done.

Comment: @Ramhound How is an extension method "really not suitable?"

Comment: @jmh_gr - When there is a perfectly valid String.Equals method it makes no sense, to extend the String class with your own method, when the method is going to do the samething as the Equals method.

Comment: @Porges = If you don't understand the reason I would make the comment about not using "==" to compare to object then I am not going to bother to explain the reason.  He knew what his strings would contain, if they contained "Apple" and "APPLE" then he should have known to use the Equal/Compare methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a string extension method?:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static bool EqualsIC(this string self, string string1) {
        return self.Equals(string1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);        
    }
}
```

Then you can just use

```
string string1 = "Hello world";
string string2 = "hEllO WOrLD";
bool theymatch = string1.EqualsIC(string2);

// OR (per TimS' comment) - to avoid error if string1 is null
theymatch = StringExtensions.EqualsIC(string1, string2);
```

As an esoteric alternative, you could use Regex instead of String.Compare:

```
public static bool EqualsICRX(this string self, string string1) {
    return Regex.IsMatch(string1, "^" + self + "$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use string.Equals(...) instead of string.Compare(...) == 0.

Comment: Hm..something to keep in mind with how you have it now is that if `self` is null, this code will throw an error.  If you instead use the static method, `string.Equals(self, ...`, you will have behavior more similar to the `==` operator, namely that nulls do not cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

`==` on strings never considers the culture, so you have to change it.

String `==` actually is done based *only* on codepoints, so strings can differ even when looking the same (e.g. if one has composed characters and the other decomposed). Generally you want a more complex notion of 'equality'.

```
"é" == "é"
== False
```